# Let $U=\Bbb{Z} \times (-\frac12,\frac12) = \{(m,y) \mid m\in \Bbb{Z}, |y| < \frac12 \}$. Show that $U$ is an open set in the metric space $(A, d_A).$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A= \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{R} \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ and let $d_A$ be the Euclidean metric restricted to $A$. Let $U=\Bbb{Z} \times (-\frac12,\frac12) = \{(m,y) \mid m\in \Bbb{Z}, |y| < \frac12 \}$. Show that $U$ is an open set in the metric space $(A, d_A).$

My idea was to define $U_0 = \{(0,y) \mid |y| < \frac12\}$ and show that this is open and since an arbitary union of open sets are open I would have that $U$ is open since $U = \bigcup_{i\in \Bbb{Z}}U_i$. I cannot seem to be able to show that $U_0$ would be open.

If I pick a point $x=(0, x_0) \in U_0$ and construct a ball $B(x,r)$ with $r = \frac12-x_0 >0$ I should be using this to show that $B(x,r) \subset U_0$? I'm getting very confused about what should be a subset of what etc in order to get this to work...

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is an open set of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $(-1/2,1/2)$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. So the product is opened in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(k,x)\in U$. Since $V:=(k-\frac{1}{4},k+\frac{1}{4})\times (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$, there is $\delta >0$ s.t.  $B_\delta (k,x)\subset V$. In particular, since $V\cap A\subset U$, $$B_{\delta }(k,x)\cap A\subset V\cap A\subset U,$$
and thus, $U$ is open.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly is $V$?

Comment: As written in my post, $V=(k-1/4,k+1/4)\times (-1/2,1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The metric space $(A,d_A)$ has the associated subspace topology $$\mathcal{T}_A=\{A\cap V|V\text{ is open in }\mathbb{R}^2\} $$ Take $$V=\mathbb{R}\times(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) $$ and show that $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. One can do this by showing that for any $z\in V$, there exists an $r>0$ such that $\{w\in\mathbb{R}^2:d(z,w)<r\}\subseteq V $ where $d$ is the usual Eucidean metric. Alternatively, you could observe that both sets are open in the usual topology on the reals, so their product is open in the usual topology on the plane.

Then $$A\cap V=(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R})\cap(\mathbb{R}\times(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}))=(\mathbb{Z}\cap\mathbb{R})\times(\mathbb{R}\cap(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}))=\mathbb{Z}\times(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=U$$ so $U$ is in $\mathcal{T}_A$.